# How to Use a Variable in host[]

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to achieve this:

```
*.numPairs = ${N=3}
**.host[0..N].udpApp[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
```

But it does not work. However, if I do like this: `**.host[0..3].udpApp[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"`, then it works properly.
It means that the problem is that the variable `N` inside `host[]` (i.e., `host[0..N]`) does not work.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue (i.e., how to make a variable work inside `host[]`)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot use a variable as an index of module.

Comment: Thank you for very direct answer.